# How to change the default name of new components

Tags: delphi, ide

Delphi sets the name of components when you add them to a form. The first TButton will be named "Button1" the second "Button2" and so on.

A while ago I discovered by accident that you can change this "prefix". Staying with TButton I changed it to "btn" so TButtons will be named "btn1", "btn2" and so on.

Now I want to change some more component prefixes but unfortunately I forgot how to do this. It could be some functionality of GExperts. Anybody to the rescue?

Just if it is important: I'm using Delphi 10.2.

Comment: That's the rename components expert. In recent versions there is a "Configure" button on the form that renames the components (Opened by default with Shift+F2). Also, you can configure this expert to automatically show this form when you insert a new component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GExperts it's called "Rename Components":
http://www.gexperts.org/tour/index.html?renamecomponents.html

To get there you have to open "GExperts Configurations" and click on "Configure" button at the right side of "Rename Components":
http://www.gexperts.org/tour/index.html?gexperts_configuration.html

There is the same functionality in CnPack in "Prefix-master"

I can be wrong a little, because I prefer CnPack, but they are similar enough, I think.

Comment: Tanks for the help. The complete path is Main Menu -> GExperts -> Configuration... -> tab Experts -> Rename Components -> button Configure...